# Removing filepath from ArcGIS geoprocessing result?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.3

This is my python script code in ArcGIS 10.3;

```
projectResult = arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
#Name of shapefiles re-projected       
arcpy.AddMessage(projectResult)
```

Which gives me this in the geoprocessing dialog result box;

```
C:\GIS_Result\abc.shp
C:\GIS_Result\1234.shp
C:\GIS_Result\zyx.shp
C:\GIS_Result\987.shp
```

Can I remove the filepath to give me just the filename?;

abc.shp
1234.shp
zyx.shp
987.shp

Comment: Please note that the question you have asked here is pure Python and should probably be researched/asked at [so] rather than [gis.se].  The distinction between the Python programming language and ArcPy (a Python site-package developed by Esri) will become more apparent as you work with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you already have the shapefile names being held in your `fc` variable so I suggest that the simplest thing will be to just use that.

```
arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
```

Comment: arcpy.AddMessage(fc) only gives me 1 shapefile name in the list.

Comment: I'm assuming that your list arose by iterating/looping something - possibly a Python list created using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` - so just place it within the same loop.

Comment: PolyGeo, Great Job. I had the arcpy.AddMessage(fc) in the loop area, but entered down a line for space and comment and maybe it broke out of the loop.

Comment: How do I leave a line space between arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages()) and arcpy.AddMessage(fc) in the dialog result box or is this a new question?

Comment: The code in your question (and my answer) does not include `arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())` so I think you should be researching/asking a new question.  Strictly speaking that would be a Python question for [so] but they will not know about ArcPy.  Search there (or Google) on something like "python new line".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name property of the [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Describe_object_properties/03q30000001w000000/) object:

```
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.Describe(projectResult).name)

>>> abc.shp
```

Or you could aslo use the baseName property, to print the name without the .shp extension:

```
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.Describe(projectResult).baseName)

>>> abc
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact there are two (may be more) ways to do this-

1. Using arcpy completely
2. using arcpy and builtin library

These are illustrated below

Suppose I have three folder input, output and template

**Method One**

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\gstack\Project\input"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
outputFolder = r"C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\gstack\Project\ouput"
template = r'C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\gstack\Project\template\Template.shp'
for i in fcs:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting "+ i)
    arcpy.Project_management(i,outputFolder+"\\"+i,template)
```

**Method Two**

If you want built-in library..

```
import arcpy,os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
inputFolder = r"C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\gstack\Project\input"
outputFolder = r"C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\gstack\Project\ouput"
template = r'C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\gstack\Project\template\Template.shp'
fcs = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(inputFolder):
    for fc in files:
        if fc.endswith(".shp"):
            fcs.append(os.path.join(root,fc))

for i in fcs:
    print i
    name =i.split("\\")[-1] 
    print name
    arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting "+ name) //you can add newline here e.g arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting "+ '\n'+name+'\n')
    arcpy.Project_management(i,outputFolder+"\\"+name,template)
```

**N.B.** You can adapt this script to tool

Comment: While correct, you could give a bit more explanation.

Comment: Take my apology, i did not get you.

Comment: Slslam,For some reason it only gives my the name of the last shapefile.